# Macro to loop through each worksheet and unfilter all tables

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote some very simple code that just loops through each sheet in a workbook, and then removes filtering (if activated) by using ActiveSheet.ShowAllData.

Here is the (updated) code:

```
 Sub removeFilters()
'This macro removes any filtering in
'order to display all of the data but it does not remove the filter arrows
On Error GoTo Errorcatch

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
If ActiveSheet.Visible = True Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
Next i

Exit Sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

The code appears to work alright, but it ends with an error, and then a MsgBox displays. Here is a screenshot of the MsgBox:

[image: Error]

The workbook has some hidden sheets, and I want to skip them entirely, which is why I added the `If` statement.

Comment: Your `On Error` statement should be *before* the processing code, and you should have `Exit Sub` before the error handler label. Also, if you are unfiltering Tables, rather than regular ranges, you should do that explicitly and ideally loop through all tables on the sheet, as there could be more than one.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct the On Error statement, but I am not sure how to loop through all the tables on a sheet, if there are multiple. Honestly I don't ever see or create workbooks with more than one table per sheet (although I am sure other people may see them a lot)

Comment: Original question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShowAllData throws an error if autofilter is not activated, so:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible Then ws.ShowAllData
Next ws
on error goto 0     'or to hell or whatever
```

Comment: Well, it worked great. I had no idea that it would throw an error if autofilter wasn't turned on. Lesson learned, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with Tables:

```
Sub removeFilters()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oList As ListObject
'This macro removes any Table filtering in
'order to display all of the data but it does not remove the filter arrows

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each oList In ws.ListObjects
            oList.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Next oList
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me perfectly.

```
    Sub resetFilter()


    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    If Wks.AutoFilterMode Then
        Wks.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    Next Wks
End Sub
```